# How do I get a Scope for the first element of an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase

I'm using AngularJS and Firebase and I have the below which is fine

```
var myTeam = Teams.child(thisTeam);   
var myFixtures = myTeam.child("fixtures").startAt(now).orderByChild("date"); 

$scope.team = $firebaseArray(myTeam);                 
$scope.fixtures = $firebaseArray(myFixtures);
```

Now I want to get the first fixture coming up and everything seems to point at being able to get it with

```
var myNextFixture = myFixtures.limitToFirst(1);  
and then  
$scope.fixtures = $firebaseArray(myFixtures);
```

but that doesn't return anything, what am I missing?

Comment: what's in `myFixtures`?

Comment: It's a bunch of game fixtures with opponents, darts and venues

Comment: i mean data structure

Comment: This is an export from Firebase

{
  "teams" : {
    "-KDJQ..." : {
      "email" : "info...",
      "fixtures" : {
        "-KDK..." : {
          "date" : 1451610060000,
          "oppos" : "1"
        },
        "-KDKq..." : {
          "date" : 1461089700000,
          "oppos" : "6"
        }
      },
      "name" : "Ninjas",
      "players" : {
        "-KDJQ..." : {
          "name" : "Dave"
        },
        "-KDKWP..." : {
          "name" : "Tobias"
        }
      },
    }
  }
}

Comment: Doesn't return anything to what? There's no return statement here. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You also are missing `orderByChild('date')` so it's unclear what your expectation is here. See [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Answer (score 0):

The line var myNextFixture = myFixtures.limitToFirst(1);
sets myNextFixture to undefined, I don't understand why.
Iwould have thought it would have set myNextFixture to the first fixture in myFixtures but it doesn't